# WebClient() never reaching DownloadStringCompleted on WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xml-parsing, webclient

So I'm confused, about why my `WebClient` is not accessing its `DownloadStringCompleted`. After reading the possible problems that the `WebClient` is being [`disposed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373172/webclients-downloadstringcompleted-event-handler-never-called), before it can finish its download. Or that [`exceptions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792608/webclient-downloadstringcompleted-never-fired-in-console-application) are not being caught during `DownloadData` or that simply the [`Uri`](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22918716?report=xml) is inaccessible.

I've checked against all these problems, and my `WebClient` has not yet accessed its `DownloadStringCompleted`.

**PMID WebClient Class**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Construct a new curl
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pmid">pmid value</param>
    public PMIDCurl(int pmid)
    {
        this.pmid = pmid;
        StringBuilder pmid_url_string = new StringBuilder();
        pmid_url_string.Append("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/").Append(pmid.ToString()).Append("?report=xml");
        this.pmid_url = new Uri(pmid_url_string.ToString());
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Curl data from the PMID
    /// </summary>
    public void CurlPMID()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(HttpsCompleted);
        client.DownloadData(this.pmid_url);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Information to store in the class after the curl
    /// </summary>
    public string AbstractTitle { get; set; }
    public string AbstractText { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve the data from an xml file about a PMID
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">System Generated</param>
    /// <param name="e">System Generated</param>
    private void HttpsCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            PMIDCrawler pmc = new PMIDCrawler(e.Result, "/pre/PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article");
            //iterate over each node in the file
            foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in pmc.crawl)
            {
                this.AbstractTitle = xmlNode["ArticleTitle"].InnerText;
                this.AbstractText = xmlNode["Abstract"]["AbstractText"].InnerText;
            }
        }
    } //close httpsCompleted
```

**PMID NodeList Constructor Class**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// List initialized by crawer
    /// </summary>
    public XmlNodeList crawl { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor for the HTML to XML converter
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nHtml"></param>
    /// <param name="nodeList"></param>
    public PMIDCrawler(string nHtml, string nodeList)
    {
        //parse it from e
        string html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(nHtml);
        XDocument htmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(html, LoadOptions.None);
        //convert the xdocument to an xmldocument
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(htmlDoc.CreateReader());
        //load the xmlDocument into a nodelist
        XmlElement xmlRoot = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
        this.crawl = xmlRoot.SelectNodes(nodeList);
    }
```

Any ideas on why the `DonwloadStringCompleted` is never reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues with your `CurlPMID` code. I have put comments in the code below.

```
public void CurlPMID()
{
    // 1. The variable 'client' loses scope when this function exits.
    //    You may want to consider making it a class variable, so it doesn't
    //    get disposed early.
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(HttpsCompleted);
    // 2. You are calling the synchronous version of the download function.
    //    The synchronous version does not call any completion handlers.
    //    When the synchronous call returns, the download has completed.
    // 3. You are calling the wrong function here.  Based on your completion handler, 
    //    you should be calling DownloadStringAsync(). If you want synchronous 
    //    behavior, call DownloadString() instead.
    client.DownloadData(this.pmid_url);
}
```

In short, assuming you want async behavior, your `CurlPMID` function should look like:

```
public void CurlPMID()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(HttpsCompleted);
    client.DownloadStringAsync(this.pmid_url);
}
```