# Encoding ASCII as HTML

Tags: c#, html, xml, ascii, webclient

I'm trying the [`DownloadData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloaddata?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) method from the [`WebClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8). My current problem is that I haven't been able to figure out how to convert the [`ASCII` result](http://pastebin.com/dFen5ywH) (`&lt;` to `<`, `\n`, `&gt;` to `>`) which is produced from `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer);`, out of this [page](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22918716?report=xml).

[image: pagesource]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/z4f2wggp.evi.png))</sub>

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Curl data from the PMID
    /// </summary>
    private void ClientPMID(int pmid)
    {
        //generate the URL for the client
        StringBuilder pmid_url_string = new StringBuilder();
        pmid_url_string.Append("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/").Append(pmid.ToString()).Append("?report=xml");
        Uri PMIDUri = new Uri(pmid_url_string.ToString());
        //declare and initialize the client
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        // Download the Web resource and save it into a data buffer. 
        byte[] myDataBuffer = client.DownloadData(PMIDUri);
        this.DownloadCompleted(myDataBuffer);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Crawl over the binary from myDataBuffer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="myDataBuffer">Binary Buffer</param>
    private void DownloadCompleted(byte[] myDataBuffer)
    {
        string download = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer);
        PMIDCrawler pmc = new PMIDCrawler(download, "/pre/PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article");
        //iterate over each node in the file
        foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in pmc.crawl)
        {
            string AbstractTitle = xmlNode["ArticleTitle"].InnerText;
            string AbstractText = xmlNode["Abstract"]["AbstractText"].InnerText;
        }
    }
```

Code for PMIDCrawler is available on my other SO question regarding the [`DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374328/webclient-never-reaching-downloadstringcompleted-on-wpf-application). Although output from `string html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(nHtml);` is not valid [HTML (OR XML)](http://pastebin.com/hjCwhEhL) (Due it not responding to `xml` http headers), after receiving content from `Encoding.ASCII.GetString`.

Comment: Here is how to do it with javascript for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this server does not respond correctly to `Accept: text/xml` or `Accept: application/xml` so you'll have to do this the hard way ([HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx))

```
string download = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer));
```

(or [WebUtility.Decode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354.aspx) on .NET Fx 4.5+)

or

```
string download = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer);
if (download != null) { // this won't get all HTML escaped characters...
    download = download.Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&gt;", ">");
}
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c) for more information.

Comment: +1 for a good suggestion so far, but anyway to get around the fact that each `attribute` is being escaped? for instance [<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>](http://pastebin.com/hjCwhEhL)

Comment: Make sure the `\"` and `\n` you are seeing are not just artifacts of the Visual Studio debugger if you're inspecting a string while at a breakpoint (that used to get me all the time). You can verify with a `Console.WriteLine` if I'm remembering my C#/.NET correctly.

Comment: Are you certain? `curl --header "Accept:text/html" http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22918716\?report\=xml` is showing me the HTML entity escaped "XML" but no `\n` nor `\"` tokens.

Comment: I do have a feeling the `Encoding.ASCII` is causing the characters to become escaped, I'm not 100% though.

Comment: you're correct, it must be an artifact. I was checking at the wrong time during debugging.

Comment: `Encoding.ASCII` shouldn't be to blame here since that's a honest to goodness conversion from a byte array to the associated ASCII characters. If anything I'd suspect `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` first so try the `download.Replace...` if you're 100% certain its not just VS "helpfully" representing a string literal